# I have a Broadcastreceiver to detect when an outgoing call ends. How should I write a method which returns a boolean value if call has ended?

Tags: android, android-studio, call, android-broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I have the following **BroadcastReceiver** to detect when an outgoing call has just ended:

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("APP", "ACTION:" + intent.getAction());

    if (Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      final String originalNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
      Log.d("APP", "outgoing,ringing:" + originalNumber);
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to write a boolean method which return true if a call has just ended, and false otherwise. How is it possible?

```
public boolean callHasEnded {
  //what should I write here?
}
```

Just to be clear in the manifest I have the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

<receiver android:name=".MyPhoneReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You can set a static variable to `true` from `onReceive`, and start a timer, which resets its value to `false` after the desired period. Then you can get the value of the variable, to see if a call has just ended, or not...

Comment: @nvi9 thanks for your answer. can you show me it in an example?

Comment: @ÁrminBéda Note that the receiver you have registered will be called when an outgoing call is about to be placed not when an outgoing call ends. See this [ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)